# Raising NOFILE limit on android

Tags: android

my app is a HTTP stress testing app and usually hits the 1024 file descriptor limit pretty fast, what is the "correct" way to raise the limit?

Comment: Probably to run the HTTP stress test on another piece of hardware, such as one running a desktop OS. AFAIK, there is no way to change this limit short of a ROM mod.

Comment: not even on a rooted phone/tablet?, i was under the impression there's supposed to be a /etc/security/limits.conf file that is used to set limits, turns out it's not used by android.

Comment: I can't rule out root having an option to affect it.